# why does boost mpl set allow non-unique types

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

I believe my understanding of **boost::mpl::set** must be fundamentally flawed.  I thought it only allowed unique types.

But the following code compiles:

```
#include <boost/mpl/set.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/accumulate.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/plus.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/sizeof.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
using namespace boost::mpl;

typedef set<long,float,long> my_set; //long repeated in set?
typedef vector<long,float,long> my_vec; //seems reasonable

typedef accumulate<
  my_set
  , int_<0>
  , plus<_1, sizeof_<_2>>
  >::type set_size;

typedef accumulate<
  my_vec
  , int_<0>
  , plus<_1, sizeof_<_2>>
  >::type vec_size;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_RELATION( vec_size::value, ==, sizeof(long)+sizeof(float)+sizeof(long) );
//why does the following line compile?
//shouldn't the size be sizeof(long)+sizeof(float) instead?
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_RELATION( set_size::value, ==, sizeof(long)+sizeof(float)+sizeof(long) );
```

Comment: Is `typedef set<long,float,long> my_vec;` meant to be `typedef vector<long,float,long> my_vec;`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look again at the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/set.html).

The list of types `T1, T2, T3, ..., TN` used to construct a set must not contain any duplicates. (Or put differently - the `set<T1, T2, ..., TN>` construct only has a well defined meaning if `T1, T2, T3, ..., TN` does not contain any duplicates).

[Later on](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/set.html#nonunique-set-example) in the documentation there is an example of how to construct a set from a list of elements which may contain duplicates:

```
typedef fold<
  vector<long,float,long>
, set0<>
, insert<_1,_2>
>::type s;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_RELATION( size<s>::value, ==, 2 );
```

The set invariants are only enforced if you use the set interface to create the set.

Comment: An interesting point is that the result of `fold<...>::type` is not an `mpl::set` but `boost::mpl::s_item<float, boost::mpl::s_item<long, boost::mpl::set0<mpl_::na> > >`, I am also missing something. In Boost.Fusion this is resolved with the `as_set` metafunction (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/conversion/functions/as_set.html), but I can't find the same in Boost MPL.

Comment: Found the solution to my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585599/how-to-obtain-standard-mpl-sequence-after-fold